# How to give dynamic extra space after last cell in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Let's say I have a `UITableView` with dynamic content, but imagine it with one section consisting of a table header of 100px and 6 rows á 44px.
Keep in mind that there could potentially be 1 section with 2 rows, or 4 sections with 10 rows etc., completely dynamic.

When the tableView displays its content I would not be able to scroll at all (only bounce) because all of the content in the tableView is visible to begin with.

I need to be able to scroll away the section header of 100px, giving more empty space at the bottom. Just enough space so that the header is outside, and the first cell is at the very top.

To achieve this, I *could* store a prototype instance of every different cell and "manually" calculate the height of the total cells, then add a phantom cell (or a section footer) with the remaining height needed. I feel like there should exist a better way though.

In cases where the collective cells heights are larger than the visible screen, then I'd like everything to be normal, no extra space at the bottom.

I tried manually setting the `tableView.contentSize` after `reloadTable` to be `max(tableView.bounds.size.height+100, tableView.contentSize)`, but it seems like contentSize is overridden no matter what I do, so I'm trying to find other ways to do it.

Comment: does  the cells in the tableview have the same height?

Comment: @shannoga Not necessarily.

Comment: Thinking about your issue I don't think you have a cleaner way to do this. The only solution I could think of is to set the header in a scroll view and nest another tableView that will hold the content. But that is pretty ugly :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked perfectly

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    let visibleHeight = self.tableView.bounds.size.height - self.topLayoutGuide.length - self.bottomLayoutGuide.length
    var actualContentSize = visibleHeight - (self.tableView.contentSize.height - (header.bounds.size.height - header.subviewThatShouldBeVisibleIfAny.bounds.size.height))
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *){
        //Nothing
    }else{
        actualContentSize += self.bottomLayoutGuide.length
    }
    var inset = self.tableView.contentInset
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *){
        inset.bottom = max(actualContentSize, 0)
    }else{
        inset.bottom = max(actualContentSize, self.bottomLayoutGuide.length)
    }
    self.tableView.contentInset = inset
}
```

`viewDidLayoutSubviews` will be invoced on its own, but I also have to call it manually whenever I update the data in the tableView.

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for this. Change the content offset according to your needs.

```
self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 100);
```

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for, no.. This simply sets the scroll position to where I want it to be. As soon as the user touches the view, it will bounce back, because the contentSize is smaller. I don't want to set the scroll position, I want the user to be able to scroll there by themselves.